# Material ui position sticky not working in my Next JS project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, sticky, box

```
<Box width={'30%'} >
    <Box sx={{ position: 'sticky', top: '100px', transition: 'all .4s ease' }}>
       {/* My render elements */}
    </Box> 
</Box>
```

Im trying solve this problems but it doesn't work and i am not knowing what happened ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the `Box` inside another element and set there the `sticky` attribute like this:

```
const StickyElement = ({ children }) => {
  return <div style={{ position: 'sticky', top: '10px' }}>{children}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ minHeight: '300vh', position: 'sticku', top: '10px' }}>
      <StickyElement>
        <Box width={'30%'}>
          <Box
            sx={{
              backgroundColor: 'primary.dark',
              position: 'sticky',
              top: '100px',
              transition: 'all .4s ease',
            }}
          >
            {/* My render elements */}
            <h1>Some content</h1>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </StickyElement>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fbqkn6?file=App.tsx